# Command line history from a certain time period?

Tags: bash, shell, command-history

How do I get command line history from a certain time frame, for example, a list for December 2021? Using bash shell.

Answer (score 6):

For `bash`, unless you *already* have `history` datetime stamping enabled with the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable, you can't do that. Going forward you can enable timestamping by providing a value for `HISTTIMEFORMAT`. For example,

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT=$'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\t'
```

The documentation (`man bash`) writes,

> **`HISTTIMEFORMAT`** If  this variable is set and not null, its value is used as a format string for *strftime*(3) to print the time stamp associated with  each  history  entry  displayed  by the history builtin.  If this variable is set, **time stamps are written to the history file so they may be preserved across shell  sessions.** This uses the history comment character to distinguish timestamps from other history lines.

Once you have that enabled, the `history` command will show the datestamp for each command in its output.

I cannot reply for other shells.

Comment: Of course the limits set in `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` still apply. So one may need to set them to negative values for unlimited length - the standard values of 1-2000 may very likely not reveal commands from December.